# SVN Granural post commit mail hook

Tags: svn

Is there ready solution for post commit hook for sending mails that supports
finer granularity, e.g.

I have few groups of interests, developers only interested in changes in trunk,
developers interested in changes only in some specific sub directories of the trunk.

By default post-commit hook support per repo mails.

Answer (score 0):

We couldn't find an off-the-peg way to do it. We ended up modifying [svnmailer](http://freshmeat.net/projects/svnmailer/) such that for each affected directory it looks for a subversion property listing email addresses (and does this for every directory up to the repository root) and builds up a set of email addresses to use as recipients.

It works pretty well, and lets developers register themselves for notifications by setting the property.